# Appending items to a list in foor loop

Tags: python, list, loops, append, list-comprehension

```py
answer = []
answer.append(i for i in [1,2,3,4,5])
print(answer)
```

I wrote this code to append every item in the list to the 'answer' variable. However, I got `[<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f56380f4890>]`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `answer = [answer.append(i) for i in [1,2,3,4,5]]`

Comment: If you are looking to concatenate two lists, use `extend` like `listA.extend(listB)`. The above comments is also wrong, as it will create a list of `None` values.

Comment: @SulemanElahi don't use list comprehensions for side-effects. A list comprehension is meant for when you want to build a loop. Your line of code will fail, because `answer.append` returns `None`, so after doing all that work, the list comprehension creates a useless list of `None`s. Now, normally that would just be wasted work because you'd throw that list away immediately, but in your case you then go on to assign that list of `None`s to `answer`, leaving you with a list of `None`s for all that hard work you just made the computer do!

Comment: OP, congratulations! You have unlocked _[¡¡generators!!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756096/understanding-generators-in-python)_

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between Python's list methods append and extend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-list-methods-append-and-extend)

Answer (score 2):

To print the list of elements that are appended to answer, you can use a loop to iterate through the list comprehension and append each element to answer:

```
answer = []
for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
    answer.append(i)
print(answer)
```

Alternatively, you can use the `extend` method to add all the elements from the list comprehension to answer at once:

```
answer = []
answer.extend(i for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print(answer)
```

Comment: No need of iterating again in extend. It can be just `answer.extend([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])`